# Referenciar dato subsonculta sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente transacción:

```
    SELECT Fecha_Llegada,COUNT(1) FROM RESERVA_ESTABLECIMIENTO_HOSTELERO 
        WHERE Fecha_Llegada BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31' 
    GROUP BY Fecha_Llegada 
    HAVING COUNT(Fecha_Llegada) > (SELECT SUM(SUB.Fecha)/COUNT(SUB.Fecha) AS TOTAL FROM
                                     (SELECT COUNT(Fecha_Llegada) AS Fecha FROM PROYECTO_ABD.RESERVA_ESTABLECIMIENTO_HOSTELERO 
                                      WHERE Fecha_Llegada 
                                      BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
                                      GROUP BY Fecha_Llegada) 
                                      AS SUB);
```

Lo relativo a qué es lo que hace no es importante. Lo que quiero es referenciar en el resultado al alias 'Total' que he creado en el primer nivel de la subconsulta, al igual que hago con el alias SUM, que recoge la tabla que surge del segundo nivel de la subconsulta. Y con dicho alias accedo a SUB.Fecha.

Me gustaría hacer algo del estilo:

```
    SELECT RESULTADO.TOTAL,Fecha_Llegada,COUNT(1) FROM RESERVA_ESTABLECIMIENTO_HOSTELERO 
        WHERE Fecha_Llegada BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31' 
    GROUP BY Fecha_Llegada 
    HAVING COUNT(Fecha_Llegada) > (Subconsula_que_no_escribo_enteder_mejor_lo_que_quiero) AS RESULTADO;
```

Pero a mysql no le gusta. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que es un *valor escalar* puedes hacer un `JOIN` con la subconsulta, y
para incluir la columna en el `HAVING` podrías incluirla en el `SELECT`:

```
SELECT Fecha_Llegada, COUNT(1), tot.TOTAL 
  FROM RESERVA_ESTABLECIMIENTO_HOSTELERO 
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM(SUB.Fecha)/COUNT(SUB.Fecha) AS TOTAL 
             FROM ( SELECT COUNT(Fecha_Llegada) AS Fecha 
                      FROM PROYECTO_ABD.RESERVA_ESTABLECIMIENTO_HOSTELERO 
                      WHERE Fecha_Llegada 
                      BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
                      GROUP BY Fecha_Llegada
                  ) AS SUB
         ) tot
  WHERE Fecha_Llegada BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31' 
  GROUP BY Fecha_Llegada 
  HAVING COUNT(Fecha_Llegada) > tot.TOTAL
```